# powershell version number compare

Tags: powershell

I need to compare 2 version numbers.

```
$version = '1.9.0'
$shareversion = Get-Content -Path \\Network-Share\some_file.txt
```

some_file.txt file has only the value `1.1.0`

```
[Version]$version -lt [Version]$shareversion
```

Output is True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you checked the value of `$shareversion`? Must be something wrong with your file or path because when you hardcode the `$shareversion` the output is `False` - as expected:

```
$version = '1.9.0'
$shareversion = '1.1.0'

[Version]$version -lt [Version]$shareversion
```

**Output:**

```
False
```

Comment: There are probably multiple lines is the file,try: `(Get-Content -All -Path \\Network-Share\some_file.txt).Trim()`

Comment: One caveat: .NET does not compare "missing" LSB as zero, such that `([Version] "1.0") -eq ([Version] "1.0.0")` is `$false`. (IMO .NET is not doing the right thing here, but at least we can be aware of the behavior and can work around it.)